Informations about a sequence from tail behaviour
Suppose $\{c_n\}_n$ is a sequence of non negative reals. We have the following three informations about it.
(a) $\sum_{k \ge n}c_k \sim \frac{1}{2n}$
(b) $\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{kc_k}{\log n} \to \frac{1}{2}$
(c) $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2c_k}{n}$ converges.
Can we conclude any information about the sequence from it? It is tempting to guess $c_k \sim \frac{1}{2k^2}$ but that certainly requires a proof. Also, is it necessarily true that $\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}$ is bounded? Any suggestion regarding this is highly appreciated. It will be of great help even if one can provide some references for similar problems.

If you consider a random variable $X$ with value in ${2, 3, \dots, \infty}$ and $P[X= n] = c_n$, your problem can be rephrased as, is such a random variable "unique" if $\mathbb{P}[X \geq n] \sim 1/(2n)$, $\mathbb{E}[X \mathbf{1}{X \leq n}] \sim \log(n)/(2n)$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^2 \mathbf{1}{X \leq n}]$ converges ? I suspect that there is no unicity, but I don't have a counter-example yet.

I don't necessarily require uniqueness. I just need information about $c_n$ for large $n. $

Yes that's why I put quotes on unicity. It think that something like $c_n = \alpha/n^2$ if n is even and $c_n = (1 - \alpha)/n^2$ if n is odd with $\alpha \neq 1/2$ might provide a counter example.

Maybe I missed something, but there should be $\sum_{k \ge n} c_k$ and $k$ for second and third series?

@openspace No, the problem posted is valid.
